# Generate Safari Developer Certificate for building extensions

Tags: safari, certificate, safari-extensions

I have gone through this [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169262/generating-safari-developer-certificate-from-windows-the-old-instructions-that).But everything seems to be changed.
Everything redirects to [Apple Development Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/).So is it mandatory to enroll in that development program to create a safari development certificate to create extensions?

And if so where can I get that certificate from?

Answer (score 1):

Apple unified all the developer programs (iOS, Mac and Safari) under one umbrella program entitled [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/). This is what you need to [enrol](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/) with to obtain a certificate for Safari extensions.